# how to have UITabBarController have tabBarSelection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

how to have `UITabBarController` TabBarSelection highlight
Please see the below attachment screen for in detailed view.
Your feedback will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want original image in background of all one use the code below

use the tint color for selected image.

```
[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem] initWithTitle:@"Recent" image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"d.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-recentB.png"]];
```